# Facebook App: automatically adding users that sign in to be Test Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app that requires a Facebook app. The customers want to test it out. It would be quite annoying to have them call me to add them to the `Test Users` of the Facebook app in order to allow them to login. Is it possible to just allow them to sign in and if they are not in the `Test User` list to automatically add them to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is unpublished you have to add users as test users in order for them being able to use the app.
You could also simply publish the app. Every other facebook account can use the application then. Published does not mean it shows up everywhere, but other accounts than the ones listed in the roles section can sign in with the app.

Comment: Does publish mean I have to submit it for review. I'm really not ready to release it for review to FB.

Comment: No, you don't have to do that.